# Does urlfetch trigger on closed Googlesheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

I built a spreadsheet which uses an API to call for financial data. It worked for a while but, now whenever I go to use it I get a "Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch (Line 127)".

My buddy has the same copy of the spreadsheet and doesn't seem to get these issues. Therefore I am wondering if I have Googlesheets which use an API/urlfetch, if they are closed are they eating up my Google Quotas (20,000calls I believe)? or will my API/urlfetch only happen on spreadsheets which are open?

Any help is hugely appreciated,
Seb

Comment: I presume you have this in a loop.  Have you tried Utilities.sleep() just to slow down the rate.

Comment: I created an on/off switch so that once I have pulled the data I can turn the urlfetch off. I'll have a look into the Utilities.sleep() and see if that helps.

Comment: Generally, I find that it looks like Google doesn't wait for a  whole day to see if you have went over the quota.  Instead they appear to do a rate calculation and if your rate over a given amount of time would exceed the daily quota over 24 hours then you get the error.  So assuming that your not actually using more than your quota then slowing down your rate of usage should suffice.

Comment: Ahh makes sense. Thanks a lot Cooper. I'll have a dig around later and try implement a sleep() function.

Comment: Yes, the [quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) for URLfetch is 20,000 per day for consumeraccounts. Hard to say how you surpassed this quota without seeing your code, but keep in mind that the quotas are per user, not per document. So if your have several scripts that run several times per day, you could reach the quota.

Comment: It’s weird I have made sure to close all google drive documents and left them closed the last couple days and last night I opened up the google sheet which keeps getting this error and again I got the error yet nothing has been open for 2 days so I’m now feeling like even closed sheets are eating into my quota. It’s all so confusing.

Comment: I have just opened Google Drive for the first time today and opened a Googlesheet which has a single API call function. I triggered it once and immediately got this error message. I have no idea how I could have hit the 20,000 per day quota as I havent used it. Not only that but after checking the API data feed I subscribe to it says I only called the data feed once. Therefore something in my Googledrive even when closed is eating up 20,000 calls. Anybody know what classifies as a call and whether closed Google Sheets can trigger a call?

Comment: Maybe you have some triggers running in the background (e.g. time-driven) that keep calling URL fetch even if you don't touch your data?